# is there a C# equivalent for Python's self-documenting expressions in f-strings?

Tags: python, c#, string-interpolation

Since Python 3.8 it is possible to use [self-documenting expressions in f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) like this:

```
>>> variable=5
>>> print(f'{variable=}')
variable=5
```

is there an equivalent feature in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
int variable = 5;
Console.WriteLine($"variable={variable}");
```

That outputs:

```
variable=5
```

The key here is the `$` that precedes the string literal.

---

To do what you want with the name coming dynamically, I'd suggest a more explicit approach of using an extension method. Try this:

```
public static class SelfDocExt
{
    public static string SelfDoc<T>(
        this T value,
        [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string name = "")
        => $"{name}={value}";
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
int variable = 5;
Console.WriteLine($"{variable.SelfDoc()}");
```

It solves your problem without breaking string interpolation.

Comment: This would be my preferred solution as well. Instead of rigidly trying to cling to specific features of one language (Python) in another (C#), I would first try to investigate any straightforward features of that other language (C#). In most cases, standard string interpolation functionality should do just fine.

Comment: Yup, that's the obvious way :) I was looking for is a way to prevent inconsistencies between the variable name and the string literal, due to typos or renames etc. I think using `nameof` in the interpolation will do the trick for me

Comment: @Adam.Er8 - Oh, gotcha. I see what you mean now. Adassko's answer is probably what you need, but it looks like it would break the actual built-in string interpolation feature. It's probably only useful in small test cases.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 - I've added a different solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity. Got an error trying this, looking at examples I think it should be `[CallerArgumentExpression("value")]` (which works for me)

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can use `InterpolatedStringHandler` and `CallerArgumentExpression` to write it yourself:

```
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public ref struct SelfDocumentingStringHandler
{
    StringBuilder builder;

    public SelfDocumentingStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount)
    {
        builder = new StringBuilder(literalLength);
    }

    public void AppendLiteral(string s)
    {
        builder.Append(s);
    }

    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T t, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(t))] string member = "")
    {
        builder.Append(member + "=");
        builder.Append(t);
    }

    internal string GetFormattedText() => builder.ToString();
}

void Print(ref SelfDocumentingStringHandler stringHandler)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stringHandler.GetFormattedText());
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
var variable = 5;
Print($"{variable}"); // prints: variable=5
```

Comment: Oh I was just about to write this! :)

Comment: Nice. But IMHO this would create a lot of additional overhead that may cause confusion with "regular" C# developers, thus increasing maintenance costs and learning curves for any new members in the C# team. I do like this answer, because it points to an interesting solution, but for simple scenarios (like the OP's one) I would personally fall back to simple and straightforward string interpolation techniques in C#.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It does not reproduce Python's feature; you are simply hacking the way string interpolation (with similar, but not identical syntax) works in C#. But now you are stuck with the new behavior for any other standard C# interpolation. A valid solution would be if you could parse `"{variable=}"` as self documenting and `"{variable}"` as standard C# string interpolation, good luck with that.

Comment: @InBetween: yes but if he needs it, it's probably for logging purposes. I just presented possible solution for this problem and there are already logging wrappers that utilize this idea. If you want to mix and match normal behavior with this, you can always create for example a function that will do the "self documenting" feature and return a string, in this case you can use it like `Console.WriteLine(Format($"{variable}") + $" - normal string interpolation {variable}")` but I think that's rather an uncommon requirement

Comment: @InBetween: another idea (just for fun) to mimic the python behavior more - you can introduce some constant let's say `const string DOC = ""` and use it as a marker for self documenting. Then you can replace one line there with `if (member.EndsWith(" + DOC")) builder.Append(member[..^6] + "=");` and use it like `Print($"{variable + DOC} {variable}")` - now the first occurence will self document and the second won't

Comment: That's cool, thanks :) I think the best thing I got out of it is the use of `nameof`, because what I was looking for is a way to prevent inconsistencies between the variable name and the string literal, due to typos or renames etc.